# Using Flutter & Firebase, how to check if a user has signed in the app (phone number authentication) previously or not?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Flutter with firebase_auth plugin/s from [Flutterfire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/). This is how the flow looks like in my app:

1. Initialize Firebase.
2. I use StreamBuilder to build "Landing Page" or "1st Page after logging in" depending on whether the user is logged in or not. Here's the relevant code:
   [image]

When there is no user logged in, `snapshot.data` i.e. `User` returns `null`, hence the builder builds the "Landing Page".
3. The user taps on login button and a "Login Page" gets pushed on top of our "Landing Page". Here the user inputs a phone number and taps on "Verify phone number" button which triggers following code:

```
try {
  await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: _phone,
    verificationCompleted: _verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: _verificationFailed,
    codeSent: _codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
  );
} catch (e) {
  print('Failed to verify phone number: $e');
}
```

Firebase starts to verify the phone number and sends an OTP to the phone via SMS. This triggers the `codeSent` void Callback from the above code, which causes the OTP `TextField` and a "Submit OTP" button to appear on the page.
3. User enters the OTP from SMS and taps "Submit OTP" button which triggers the following code:

```
PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    verificationId: verificationId,
    smsCode: _otpController.text.trim(),
);
await signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

Future<void> signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
    // Code to take in some user details
    // like address, topics to follow, etc.
    // These details need to be taken from
    // new users, because the "1st Page" depends
    // on them.
    return;
}
```

Now the problem is, whenever the method `signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)` finishes executing, firebase signs the user in, and this method notifies its listeners about the auth state change including the `Stream<User> authStateChanges()` which we used in step 2 above. This causes the builder to pluck the landing page(and its descendants) out of the widget tree and replaces it with "FirstPage".
Due to this, everything below the `signInWithCredentials` call is not executed.
I observed on the Firebase console that the user does get logged in. But I'm not able to take details from the new users, first thing after signup.

I learned that the `UserCredential userCredential` object has a property that tells us if the user is freshly logged in. It is obtained using this code:

```
userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
```

which return true if user is new. But I need to use it before the method `signInWithCredentials` notifies its listeners about the auth state change.

I couldn't possibly prompt the same user for entering the same details every time he/she logs in.
Help me on this.